# Magento 2.3 ElasticSearch shows item in dropdown, but not in search

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a Magento 2.3 store. We have a weird issue with ElasticSearch.

Most of the time, when i search for an SKU, we get normal results. But sometimes, it shows in the search bar dropdown that it has found one product, but when pressing enter, the product doesnt show.

Also, it's very inconsistent. After running indexer, some products are searchable again, but products that could be found in the first place, are not searchable anymore.

Anyone an idea what this could be?

Entering product SKU in searchbar. Dropdown showing 1 result:
[image: Entering SKU in search bar. Showing 1 result]

After pressing `Enter` showing no products found, but the filter on the left still shows 1 product.
[image: After pressing enter. Showing no result]

Using:
Magento 2.3.1
ElasticSearch 5.2
Smile_Elasticsuite module 2.8.1

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but magento docs about ElasticSearch point to install ElasticSearch version 6.*
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Comment: Ive changed it to 6.*. Problem came back so not the solution